# Google Closure: How do I setVisible on an Element

Tags: javascript, google-closure-compiler, google-closure, google-closure-library

While rendering the page first time I create a toolbar using `goog.ui.Toolbar`. I later add some buttons to it. Also I hide a few buttons.

```
this.mainToolbar = new components.ui.Toolbar();
this.addChild(this.mainToolbar);

var mlSelectBtn = new components.ui.ToolbarButton(content);
mlSelectBtn.setId("select");
this.mainToolbar.addChild(mlSelectBtn, true); 

var mlUnSelectBtn = new components.ui.ToolbarButton(content);
mlUnSelectBtn.setId("unselect");
this.mainToolbar.addChild(mlUnSelectBtn, true); 
mlUnSelectBtn.setVisible(false);
```

Now when I click a few other buttons on my application I want to hide select button and unhide unselect button. 
I try to do this

```
var temp = document.querySelector("[id=unselect]");
temp.setVisible(true);
```

I get an error saying setVisible is not a function. How do I set the visible back to true ?

Comment: Sorry for this stupid question but I realized I have the reference to mainToolbar.

Answer (score 1):

The result of the `querySelector` method is a DOM element, but to call `setVisible` you need a reference to the `ToolbarButton` (`mlUnSelectBtn`, above). You will need to store a reference to `mlUnSelectBtn` somewhere which can be accessed by the code which resets the visibility.